# Meaning of e2fsck pass 5 output

Tags: e2fsck

I'm using `e2fsck -B 4096 /path/to/image.dd` (of a drive that 'broke') and I know it reached phase 5 in its process, outputting:

```
(lost info preceding (-scrolled-out-of-buffer-space-) the following lots
of output like this)
...
+(243859456--243859969) +(243892224--243892737) +(243924992--243925505)
+(243957760--243958273) +(243990528--243991041) +(244023296--244023809) 
+(244056064--244056577) +(244088832--244089345) +(244121600--244122113)
+(244154368--244154881) +(244187136--244187649)
Fix<y>?
```

I googled for info on what it means but failed to find any explanation.
What does it mean and should I say 'y'?

Answer (score 0):

Most terminal(-emulator)s have a scroll back-buffer, are you sure you can't go back and see what `e2fsck` said before all those numbers? The description of the phases of `e2fck` I could find says

> Phase 5: Check Cylinder Groups - checks free blocks and the used inode maps for consistency

So those numbers are probably blocks that `e2fsck` can't tell whether should be free or not. I think (luckily it's been quite a while since I had to use fsck on a dead disk, so there's no guarantee the outcome is the totaly opposite) it will mark those blocks as used and create files in `/lost+found` (with the block numbers as names) if you answer 'y'.

Comment: I should have said 'scrolled-out-of-buffer', my bad. I also guess something like that, but I want to be sure ...